# localstorage.getData is not working properly with JSON in Phone gap

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, local-storage

I have an issue in local storage
this is my JSON String

```
data = {"person" : [{"FirstName":  fname }, {"LastName"  : lname }]};
```

Now i am storing it in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem( "data", data );
```

but when i use

```
data = localStorage.getItem("data");
```

when i check it,it shows me

```
[Object Object]
```

I dont know where i go wrong please help me out.

I have tried all case as check in array and all but still it shows me same.

Comment: `data` isn't JSON. It's a javascript object. Try `JSON.stringify`ing it first.

Comment: i have also tried that but still its not working

Comment: show this attept as well, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the object like this:

```
localStorage.setItem( "data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

and read like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```